# Random sampling from different class

Tags: python, pandas

I am totally new in this area. I tried to find the solutions but couldn't get exactly like this. I am doing the code in **python Jupyter using pandas** library. 
I know the code for sampling. Which is `df = data.sample(frac =.1)`
But can't understand how to write the code for this.

Dataset:

[image]

I have this dataset. I want to choose 2 rows randomly from each class(Rings). Following is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO; please be reminded that it is *not* a code writing or tutorial service.

Comment: Thanks. I will remind that.

Comment: May be my procedure of finding solution is wrong. I edited the problem. May be it is not a tutorial service. This part is a tiny part of my implementation. My approach can be wrong as I am a new user in SO. I know that it is 1 line code but I can't make it. If you have any suggestions regarding my problem kindly share it. @desertnaut

Comment: If I had, I would certainly share, but I don't; good thing you edited your question, and at least it is clear now what you are after (it wasn't before).

Comment: You could use something like, `df.groupby('Rings').apply(lambda x: x.sample(2)).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Shell(g)": np.random.random(14), "Rings": [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]})
```

**Code**

```
# shuffle
result = df.sample(frac=1.0)

# get the first two by group
result = result.groupby("Rings").head(2)

# sort by Rings
result = result.sort_values("Rings")

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
    Shell(g)  Rings
1   0.950714      3
0   0.374540      3
3   0.598658      4
2   0.731994      4
7   0.866176      5
6   0.058084      5
12  0.832443      6
10  0.020584      6
```